# Djanog limit image upload size

Tags: django

I am attempting to limit the size of an image that can be uploaded. To do this in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size) I found `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` I set the value of it to 3mb (3145728 bytes) in my settings.py file but I am still able to upload files larger than 3 mb. I also tried `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` and the same thing occurred. The only way i can get it to trigger is if i set it to a very low value such as 1 or 2. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you try this on your local machine or somewhere else? On Heroku, for example, you can't really upload anything because of restrictions, but you're forced to use S3 or something similar to upload your stuff to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size), it does not include uploaded files.

> The check is done when accessing request.body or request.POST and is calculated against the total request size **excluding any file upload data**.

[FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size) defines when an uploaded file is saved to the filesystem instead of staying in memory, it does not impose any limits on how large the uploaded file can be

Your best bet is to configure your webserver to limit upload size, [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) if you are using nginx for example